# uninitialized constant error when trying to include class/object association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have been trying to pass an **User** object to a variable and include its **UserSettings** relative object using the `includes` method:

```
logged_user = User.includes(:user_settings).find_by(login: login)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
"error": "uninitialized constant User::UserSettings"
```

Here are the classes' definitions:

```
class UserSetting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end 

class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :user_settings, :class_name => 'UserSettings'
  has_many :sessions

  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is just a typo, right?  You wrote `UserSettings` in one place and `UserSetting` in the actual class definition.

Comment: Good point, I'm not yet familiar with RoR's pluralization rules. However, I just tried to change ```UserSetting``` to ```UserSettings```and got the same error. 
I also tried to change every ```user_settings``` call to ```user_setting``` and it didn't trigger any errors, but returned a null value even though there are actual registers on the database.

Comment: It's just `has_one :user_setting` and `User.includes(:user_setting)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
has_one :user_settings, :class_name => 'UserSettings'
```

try to change association plural `user_settings` to `user_setting` and you can remove `class_name` or remove plural `UserSettings` to singularly `UserSetting`, it will be like this:

```
has_one :user_setting, :class_name => 'UserSetting'
```

then change in includes `user_settings` to `user_setting`

```
logged_user = User.includes(:user_setting).find_by(login: login)
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, Saleh! It worked just fine! :D